# How can I draw sphere passing though four points without knowing center and radius?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

Based on [This paper](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/2/Marshall2-Monthly-2014.pdf), I have a Heronian Tetrahedra Are
Lattice Tetrahedra with vertices `O(0, 0, 0), A(15, -60, 20), B(96, 120, 128), C(63, 84, 56)` and
based on  [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511521/how-can-i-repair-dimension-too-large-of-the-point-s-in-this-code/511523#511523) I tried

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2 mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot-circleofsphere}
\begin{document} 
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{170} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1/10,line cap=butt,line join=round,tdplot_main_coords,declare function={R= 5*sqrt(451369)/14;%
    }] 
    \path 
    coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0) 
    coordinate (A) at (15, -60, 20) 
    coordinate (B) at (96, 120, 128)
    coordinate (C) at (63, 84, 56)
    coordinate (I) at   (-1383/14, 90/7, 1528/7)
    ; 
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords]
    \draw[thick] (I) circle (R);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

I can't obtain the result because the Dimension is too large.
Without calculating coordinates of center and radius of sphere, how can I draw the sphere passing through `O, A, B, C`?

Comment: That is one ugly tetrahedron!

Comment: @JohnKormylo I checked. It is a beautiful tetrahedron!

Answer (score 1):

I just used a hand calculator.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2 mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document} 
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{170} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1/10,line cap=butt,line join=round,tdplot_main_coords] 
    \path 
    coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0) 
    coordinate (A) at (15, -60, 20) 
    coordinate (B) at (96, 120, 128)
    coordinate (C) at (63, 84, 56)
    coordinate (I) at (-98.79, 12.86, 218.29)
    ; 
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords]
    \draw[thick] (I) circle (239.94);
    \end{scope}
    ; 
    \draw[thick] (O)--(A) (O)--(B) (O)--(C) (A)--(B) (A)--(C) (B)--(C);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to remove the `dimension too large` error, one possible answer is: with `fpu`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2 mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot-circleofsphere}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\def\pgfmathsetmacroFPU#1#2{\begingroup%
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{#2}%
\pgfmathsmuggle#1\endgroup}%

\begin{document} 
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{170} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1/10,line cap=butt,line join=round,tdplot_main_coords,
        %declare function={R= 5*sqrt(451369/(14*14));%  }
        ] 
    \pgfmathsetmacroFPU{\myR}{5*sqrt(451369)/14}
    \path 
    coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0) 
    coordinate (A) at (15, -60, 20) 
    coordinate (B) at (96, 120, 128)
    coordinate (C) at (63, 84, 56)
    coordinate (I) at   (-1383/14, 90/7, 1528/7)
    ; 
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords]
     \draw[thick] (I) circle[radius=\myR];
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not think you can obtain the center and the radius without any computations, but of course you could let LaTeX do the math.

Comment: for me, he (she) wants to ask "Without calculating coordinates of center and radius of sphere, how can I draw the sphere passing throught O, A, B, C?" in LaTeX. I think, this is a difficult question.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Thanks! I do not think it is too difficult (but it is very late here). `3dtools` has the the `circle through 3 points` in, and stores the center. So we can construct two of them and can construct the normals through the centers. Where they meet will be the center of the sphere.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat - Alternatively, construct planes from perpendicular bisectors to 3 of the edges.  Where the three planes intersect is the center.  OTOH, I have no idea how to do that using tikz.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, I agree with that. The problem with computing the intersection of planes, though, is that you need to distinguish quite a few cases since some coefficients can be 0.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 I am not currently working on that.